# SSDT Stand-alone connection to Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-data-tools

I have installed SSDT standalone from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd410fd7-6276-4fdb-8332-6bfdd2b6eb15/ssdt-for-visual-studio-code?forum=ssdt.

I then installed Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64) 64-bit from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html and added this to my path.

I then tried created a data source of Type "OLE DB" with OleDB Provider = "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle". However when I test the connection I get "Oracle Client and Networking components were not found".

Is it possible to get a connection to Oracle from SSDT standalone? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. 
Download ODAC for Oracle then Choose OLE DB\Oracle Provider for OLE DB in your Data Flow task.

For Server name: use "Servername/ServiceName"

I have a sucessfully connected using Visual Studio/SSDT 2019 to Oracle 11g (Oracle OLE DB) and moved data to Netezza. (Netezza OLE DB)